# How to parse a range of numbers?

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

```
> dput(range)
structure(list(Range = c("0T-1T", "2T-5T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to parse these values out, so that the final dataframe looks like this:

```
> dput(range2)
structure(list(Range = c("0T", "1T", "2T", "3T", "4T", "5T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution with `tidyr::separate_longer_delim()` + `tidyr::full_seq()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

range %>%
  group_by(grp = Range) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Range, '-') %>%
  reframe(Range = paste0(full_seq(parse_number(Range), 1), 'T')) %>%
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 6 × 1
#   Range
#   <chr>
# 1 0T
# 2 1T   
# 3 2T
# 4 3T
# 5 4T
# 6 5T
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a cleaner way but here is one way:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
structure(list(Range = c("0T-1T", "2T-5T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                 -2L)) %>% 
    mutate(
        Range = str_split(Range, '-'),
        Range = map(Range, str_remove, 'T'),
        Range = map(Range, as.integer),
        Range = map(Range, ~ paste0('T', seq(.x[1], .x[2], 1)))
    ) %>% 
    unnest(Range)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>   Range
#>   <chr>
#> 1 T0   
#> 2 T1   
#> 3 T2   
#> 4 T3   
#> 5 T4   
#> 6 T5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Assumes to only expand withing each "XT-YT" pair rather than the full range (which would be easier for sure).